# UWP CalenderView Set Date And Focus

Tags: c#, user-interface, uwp

I am having trouble setting the current date and focus to a CalendatView in Uwp.
When I press enter on a button I want to make the CalendarView visible select a date and focus on that date so that I can use the arrow keys to select another date.

```
cal.SelectionMode = CalendarViewSelectionMode.Single;
cal.SetDisplayDate(DateTimeOffset.Now.Date);
selectedDayItem.Focus(FocusState.Programmatic);
```

The selectedDayItem is a field being set in the handler:

```
private void cal_CalendarViewDayItemChanging(CalendarView sender,
                                             CalendarViewDayItemChangingEventArgs args)
{
     selectedDayItem = args.Item;
}
```

The calendar show the current date being set but the arrow keys don't seems foucused to that cell.The current selected cell which is moved by the arrow keys appears to be set in some kind of random manner? I just want the current selected cell to be where the date was set.There isn't a current selected cell to be set?

Answer (score 2):

`CalendarviewDayItemChanging` event is called whenever the display of calendar view changes and is **called for each of the dates** that are being displayed. This means it will be called for example 31 times when you go to October, and your current code will just end up with the day item that has been changed the last (which can be pretty random and depends on the implementation of the `CalendarView`). Instead you will need to check for the `CalendarViewDayItem.Date` to make sure you are getting the right one:

```
private void cal_CalendarViewDayItemChanging(CalendarView sender, 
                                             CalendarViewDayItemChangingEventArgs args)
{
    if (args.Item.Date == mySelectedDate)
    {
        selectedDayItem = args.Item;
    }         
}
```

The `selectedDayItem` now will be the instance with the selected date. However, I expect there will be a problem in case the selected date is already displayed - in which case this event will probably not fire. Unfortunately I don't have a reliable solution for this problem so far.